# Get Excel sheet name in SUM formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of sheets with various names e.g.

```
start, wc 17 Oct,  wc 24 Oct, wc 31 Oct
```

To keep a running total of various numbers in each sheet I am simply using the following in each sheet,

```
=SUM('start:wc 24 Oct'!B1)
```

Then the next sheet is,

```
=SUM('start:wc 31 Oct'!B1)
```

And so on and so forth. I know you can get the current sheet name with `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)`

However is there a way to combine the two

```
=SUM("'start:"&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&'!B1)
```

What is the correct syntax to make the above work, if it is possible?

Comment: Have a look at the [INDIRECT() Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Comment: Would you use INDIRECT for the sheet name bit, or the whole formula `=SUM(INDIRECT("'start:"&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"'!B1"))`?

Comment: @tigeravatar seems like INDIRECT doesn't work in this situation, thank you for trying though.

Comment: @TimWilkinson check this ... it might help you.. http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/921098-3d-sum-using-indirect-function.html